# SQLAlchemy + pgadmin4 Allowing Dupes on Unique Column

Tags: postgresql, sqlalchemy, pgadmin-4

Seeing some weird behavior that I can't explain while using pgadmin4 and SQLAlchemy. I have a user model with a unique constraint on email. However, when creating users in pga4, I'm able to create one duplicate email before pga4 throws a unique constraint error.

In [this screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EETbV.png), I have already successfully created a user with a duplicate email address as the first user. Then I try to create a third user with the same email address and it is throwing that constraint.

Here is my model code, it's pretty straightforward:

```
class User(Base):
    ''' Define user model '''
    __tablename__ = 'users'

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, nullable=False)
    email = Column(String, nullable=False, unique=True)
    password = Column(String, nullable=False)
    created_at = Column(TIMESTAMP(timezone=True),
                        nullable=False, server_default=text('now()'))
```

I've dropped the table a couple of times and re-created it. I created one user, saved it. Then successfully created the duplicate user and saved again. So it's not a matter of saving the first two users at the same time.

Comment: Can you [edit] the question to include the output of `\d users` in `psql` please?

Comment: The "1+" on the top row of the screenshot looks like it might be an uncommitted row. I don't recall ever seeing that in pgAdmin_4, but then I don't use it very often.

Comment: I would suggest looking at the Postgres log to see what is actually hitting the database, it might provide clues on what is happening.